# HtmlUnit click() behaves differently?

Tags: java, htmlunit

A question regarding the HtmlUnit java libary:
I've created a log on my server, and noticed that the click() method doesn't pass the "referral" information when it is invoked through a "HtmlElement" or "HtmlArea". when invoked through the more commonly used HtmlAnchor- the refferral information is passed.

This is strange since HtmlAnchor is a Subclass of HtmlElement

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's your question? The source code for `HtmlAnchor` shoes the referrer header being set.

Comment: My question will be- how to set the referrer header in other elements or in more general in the "HtmlElement".

If the HtmlAnchor is to simulate a real click
I think all other methods who use the click() method should be able to simulate as weel

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting, issue is fixed in SVN.

Next time, you may consider HtmlUnit user-list.

Comment: thanks for the fix
but it seems now the ability to cast an HtmlElement to HtmlArea is lost